# Google WebFonts Rendering

Tags: fonts, rendering, web

If I open the google [web font page](http://www.google.com/webfonts), the fonts are displayed very well (IE9, Windows 7). If I open the popout to view details about the font, I get a miserable rendering of the font:

[image: Google web fonts list- and popout view, IE9, Windows 7]

...even if I choose the same font size. If I embed a google font in a website, the rendering is exactly the same as in the popout window - miserable.

On Mac OS X, the fonts are beautiful.

- Does anyone have the same problem and / or knows a solution?
- Why is the font rendered well in the font listing on google web fonts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of different values of font-size. Text on the left was rendered without clear-type (plain gray-scale rendering). Text on the right is small enough, so browser start to use clear-type rendering engine.

You can use Ctrl + wheelup/wheeldown to watch the effect. Also I made [a page](http://yakunins.com/misc/type-test/index.html) to perform some font tests.